# Add github accounts to readme file

Tags: github, readme

How can I add links to GitHub accounts in my readme file. 
This is what I want to see:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:-

Here is my CSS:

> ```
> .photos {
>   display: inline-block;
>   position: relative;
>   width: 200px;
>   height: 200px;
>   overflow: hidden;
>   border-radius: 50%;
> }
> ```

Here is my HTML:

> ```
> <div class="photos">
> <a href="Github Profile url"> 
>   <img href="Github profile image source"> 
> </a> 
> <div class="photos">
> <a href="Github Profile url"> 
>   <img href="Github profile image soure"> 
> </a> 
> <div class="photos">
> <a href="Github Profile url"> 
>   <img href="Github profile image source"> 
> </a> 
> <div class="photos">
> <a href="Github Profile url"> 
>   <img href="Github profile image source"> 
> </a> 
> </div>
> ```

For Displaying the word "Authors" you can use

> ##Authors

Comment: I didn't know that we can use simple html and css in md files, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to do this is to use [contributors-img](https://contrib.rocks/)
 and use the following in your markdown:

```html
<a href="https://github.com/OWNER/REPO/graphs/contributors">
  <img src="https://contrib.rocks/image?repo=OWNER/REPO" />
</a>
```

[gist example](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/cbfc4177a8de71742289ed85dbb6f3ec)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is that the authors are not contributors. Sorry for not mentioning this in the question.